# How to get index of an object in JSON array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby

I have JSON array with the format below, how can I get the position (index) of an object using its key?

```
json = [
    {
        "id"=>1, 
        "user_name"=>"Mean Dean", 
        "user_profile_id"=>"1", 
        "amount"=>4
    },
    {
        "id"=>2, 
        "user_name"=>"Mad Stan", 
        "user_profile_id"=>"2", 
        "amount"=>7
    },
    {
        "id"=>3, 
        "user_name"=>"Jack Dean", 
        "user_profile_id"=>"3", 
        "amount"=>8
    }
]
```

For example how would I go about it if I wanted to get the position of the first element if I am given its id (in this case 1). I read about the [index](https://apidock.com/ruby/Array/find_index) method but don't know how to apply it to a JSON array.

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Your question title has got nothing to do with what you're actually asking. Please show *what you have tried so far*, and what has caused the error.

Comment: Didn't update from a previous question sorry for the silly mistake

Comment: [Edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44130276/edit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have your array in `json` variable, you might use [`Enumerable#detect`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-detect):

```
json.detect { |e| e['id'] == 1 }
#⇒ {
#           "amount" => 4,
#               "id" => 1,
#        "user_name" => "Mean Dean",
#  "user_profile_id" => "1"
# }
```

To get an index of this element, one would use [`Enumerable#find_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_index):

```
json.find_index { |e| e['id'] == 1 }
```

To update this object, you just update the hash returned:

```
json.detect { |e| e['id'] == 1 }['amount'] = 500
#⇒ 500
json
#⇒ [
#  [0] {
#             "amount" => 500,  ⇐ !!!!!!!
#                 "id" => 1,
#          "user_name" => "Mean Dean",
#    "user_profile_id" => "1"
#  },
#  [1] {
#             "amount" => 7,
#                 "id" => 2,
#          "user_name" => "Mad Stan",
#    "user_profile_id" => "2"
#  },
#  [2] {
#             "amount" => 8,
#                 "id" => 3,
#          "user_name" => "Jack Dean",
#    "user_profile_id" => "3"
#  }
# ]
```

Comment: I needed the position so that I could update the "amount" if an object with a given id is present, this returns the object. How would I manipulate it?